# Datatable data in vuejs and laravel is not showing on mobile

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatable

I am working with laravel and vuejs I show the data with dataTable, in the mobile version it does not show me the api data, the problem is in the mobile version that is not shown, in the desktop version if the data is shown, the edit buttons do not open in mobile version either. I have tried link an api from the internet and if it shows me the data.

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use App\Models\Admin\Dependence;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Controllers\ResponseApiController;

class DependenceController extends ResponseApiController
{
    
    public function getDependencies()
    {
        
        $dependencies = Dependence::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        
        $message = $this->sendResponse($dependencies, 'Dependencias listadas correctamente');

        return $message;
    }     
       
}
```

**Route:**

```
Route::get('dependencies', 'Admin\DependenceController@getDependencies');
```

**Vue - Libraries in global file:**

```
//DataTables
import 'datatables.net-bs4';
import 'datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js';
import 'datatables.net-bs4/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css';
import 'datatables.net-bs4/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css';
import 'datatables.net-responsive-bs4/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js';

//DataTable Global
Vue.prototype.$tableGlobal = function(table) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
        $(table).DataTable();
    });
}
```

**Template:**

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-auto mr-auto">
                            <h2 class="text-secondary">Dependencies List</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <button class="right btn btn-primary btn-sm" v-b-modal.modal-1 @click="showModal = true">Add</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body animated fadeIn">
                    <table id="tblDependencies" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Description</th>                                                                    
                                <th>Options</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr v-for="dependence in dependencies" :key="dependence.id">
                                <td>{{ dependence.description }}</td>
                                <td>                                   

                                     <!-- Change Status  -->
                                    <b-button size="sm"  @click="statusUpdate(dependence)" class="mr-1" :class="[dependence.status == 1  ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-danger']">
                                        <b-icon :icon="dependence.status == 1 ? 'check' : 'x' "></b-icon> 
                                    </b-button>
                                     
                                     <!-- Edit -->
                                     <b-button v-b-modal.editDependence size="sm" @click="editDependence(dependence)" class="btn btn-warning">                                            
                                        <b-icon icon="pencil-fill"></b-icon>
                                     </b-button>
                                     
                                </td>                                  
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
    </div>


<AddDependence ref="dependenceModal" @reload="getDependencies"></AddDependence>


<EditDependence ref="editModal" :editDependence="this.dataEditDependence" @reload="getDependencies"></EditDependence>

</div>

</template>


<script>

// Services
import * as dependenceService from '../../services/dependence';

// Components
import AddDependence from '../../components/Admin/Dependence/AddDependence.vue';    
import EditDependence from '../../components/Admin/Dependence/EditDependence.vue'

export default {

    data() {
        return {
            dependencies: [],                
            dataEditDependence: {}               
        }
    },

    mounted() {            
        this.getDependencies();
    },

    components: {            
        AddDependence,           
        EditDependence
    },
    methods: {
                
        getDependencies: async function() {

            try {
               
                const response = await dependenceService.getDependencies();                               

                if(response.status == 200) {
                    this.dependencies = response.data.data;                        
                    this.reloadTable();              
                }

            } catch (error) {
                this.loading = false
                 console.log(error);
                if (error.response.status == 422){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        },
        
        statusUpdate: async function(dependence) {
            
            try {

                const response = await dependenceService.activateDesactivate(dependence.id);

                if (response.status == 200) {
                    
                    if(response.data.data.status == 1) {
                        dependence.status = 1;
                    }else {
                        dependence.status = 0;
                    } 

                    this.$alerta('Actualizado', 'Estado actualizado correctamente', 'success');                        
                    this.reloadTable();  
                }

            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }                

        },

        editDependence(dependence) {
            this.dataEditDependence = dependence;               
        },
     
        reloadTable() {
           $('#tblDependencies').DataTable().destroy();
           this.$tableGlobal('#tblDependencies');
        },

    }
}

</script>
```

**http_service:**

```
import store from '../store';
import axios from 'axios';

export function http() {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: store.state.apiURL,
    });
}
```

**Service:**

```
import {http} from './http_service';

export function getDependencies() {
    return http().get('/dependencies');
}
```

Comment: I see u have a hover class on the table idk if u need to hover to show de data in the case u do hover doesn't work for mobile cause there is no hover effect on a mobile so u either need to make it a click event with a button for mobile

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, what kind of class do you mean?

Comment: css hover class `<table id="tblDependencies" class="table table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive">` there is table-hover in ur css

Comment: I already removed those classes but the data is not displayed

Comment: maybe it something with your fade in class but I cant be sure but I think its in your css if it works on computer but not mobile